# Creating DIV elements and adding HTML Contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no knowledge in jquery. can some body guide me what the below code does. I googled it but no result found. I want to add some HTML Contents inside the div whose class is
'p-notification'. How to do this?

```
 this.notification = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'p-notification'
 });
 this.content = $('<div/>', {
        'class': $elem.attr("hasFooter") === "true" ? 'p-content with-p-footer' : 'well',
        'style': $elem.attr("paddless") === "true" ? 'padding:0;' : '',     
        'text': 'Loading'
 });
```

Comment: The people of JQuery do have a website..

Comment: I would suggest checking the [jquery documentation for DOM Insertion](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/).

Comment: Hey Ranjan is this your issue or something else. See your question is been downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following part adds or sets the `notification` property on the scope to be a newly created `div` element with class `p-notification`:

```
 this.notification = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'p-notification'
 });
```

The next part adds or sets the `content` property on the scope to be a newly created `div` element with several attributes being preset: `class`, `style`, and `text`:

```
 this.content = $('<div/>', {
        'class': $elem.attr("hasFooter") === "true" ? 'p-content with-p-footer' : 'well',
        'style': $elem.attr("paddless") === "true" ? 'padding:0;' : '',     
        'text': 'Loading'
 });
```

By itself this will have no net effect on the DOM, since you have created elements but not inserted them into the document. You can insert them by using one of [several methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) provided by jQuery, eg `append`:

```
$('#somediv').append(this.content);//adds the div that was created to an element with id somediv
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this to add content:

```
$('.p-notification').append('<div>Hey</div>');
```

or this to replace content:

```
$('.p-notification').html('<div>Hey</div>');
```